# Problems with double curly brackets with cmdlet Get-Content of HTML files

Tags: powershell

I am calling Get-Content to retrieve an HTML Page which contains standard string place-holders (like '{0}','{1}' etc.) so to allow using the -f operator for population.

The HTML page has a CSS Styling which requires curly braces but those conflict with the -f operator.  I want to keep the HTML page compliant so I can easily view it in a browser for easy editing but the double curly brackets make a mess of this. Why are curly braces needed?

**HTML Page That Won't Load**

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            div.Content{
                background-color: red
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="Content">{0}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PowerShell Code**

```
$webPage = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtml.htm"
$webPage = $webPage -f "Hello World!"
$webPage
```

**Error**

```
Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
```

**HTML Page that Will Load and Populate the Place Holder**

*Notice the double curly braces in the style tag*

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            div.Content{{
                background-color: red
            }}
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="Content">{0}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content returns an array and not a string like it appears you are expecting.  You probably want to use the `-Raw` switch.  Even then, your method of replacing tokens could be problematic.  Using a different kind of token/format and method for replacement may scale better.

Consider using a token like "{[setting1]}" like

```
<body>
    <div class="Content">{[setting1]}</div>
</body>
```

And read your file like:

```
$htmFileTemplate = "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtml-TEMPLATE.htm"
$htmFile = "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtml.htm"
$template = Get-Content $htmFileTemplate -Raw
$template = $template.Replace("{[setting1]}", "Hello World!")
```

Optionally, use HtmlDecode so your hlinks work...

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($template) | Out-File $htmFile -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced the Get-Content line with the HtmlDecode idea but still fails.  I also tried the -raw switch which also fails.  Looks like I'm sticking with double curly brackets.  Would love to hear from @DonJones or someone like that about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest *not* using the `-f` format command.

You will be hard pressed to get around the  issue.  The only hack I can see is passing it through a regex replace filter that would double up braces when it detects `{\d}`.  If you're going to have to use `replace` anyhow...

Just use the `-replace` function and define your own replace pattern.

```
$webPage = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtml.htm"

# define your first replace with {{new_word}}
$webPage = $webPage -replace "{{new_word}},"Hello World!"
$webPage
```

If you are doing this many times, try this function I wrote, it will allow you to take a file, make the replace, and output to another file.

```
function Get-FileWithReplace {
  param(
    [string]$sourceFilename, # e.g. d:\test.txt
    [string]$targetFilename, # e.g. d:\test2.txt
    [hashtable]$replaces, # e.g. @{"FIND_KEY" = "replace with this"; ... }
    [bool]$isCaseSensitive = $false
  )

  Write-Host "Get-FileWithReplace $sourceFilename to $targetFilename ..." ;

  $sourceText = Get-Content $sourceFilename ;
  foreach($search in $replaces.Keys) {
    $replace = $replaces[$search] ;
    if ($isCaseSensitive -eq $true) {
      $sourceText = $sourceText -creplace $search, $replace ;
    } else {
      $sourceText = $sourceText -replace $search, $replace ;
    }
  }

  $sourceText | Out-File -Encoding ASCII $targetFilename ; 
}
Get-FileWithReplace `
  -sourceFilename "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtml.htm" `
  -targetFilename "C:\Users\timothyo\Documents\TestHtmlOut.htm" `
  -replaces @{
    "{first_word}" = "First Word";
    "{pi}" = 3.14159;
  } `
  -isCaseSensitive $true ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but why would you highly recommend not using the -f operator.  It is the same as String.Format() c# I think it should be used all the time, every time formatting text.  Given my choice between double curly brackets and all this work-around code i'll choose the double curly bracket.

Comment: The longer you code in Powershell, the more you'll see the differences with a well-defined language like C#.  Keep in mind this is a scripting language with lots of quirks, shortcuts and heuristics you wouldn't ever get away with in C#.  `-f` explicitly uses curly braces, only way around that is to a) search/replace all your HTML files and add double curly and make sure your `{0}` doesn't get doubled - pain, or b) make a smart regex that adds double curly on ingest.  I think both these options are less desirable then just using `-replace` in the first place.

Comment: you can still use `{0}`, `{1}` like you would in `-f`, but i think being descriptive is better, especially when you are dealing with I18n for example.